# Matrix Algebra : Matrice * Transposed is a peculiar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

M is an n×n square matrix, containing only 0s and 1s and where each column sums to k, where k is a constant (say 5 in my case) and $~^tA.A=k.I + Ones$
(I is is the identity matrix and Ones in a n×n containing only 1s).

Is there anything I can say about M ? can I deduce n ?

so far I have

- M is full rank (as it is same rank as $~^tA=k.I + Ones$)
- and each lines sums to k (as $A~^tA=~^t(~^tA.A)=~^tA.A$

Answer (score 1):

Let's rephrase this problem more combinatorially.  Each column of your matrix corresponds to a subset of an n element base set, namely which positions have the 1's.  The condition that $A^T A$ has $k$'s along the diagonal corresponds to each subset containing exactly $k$ elements.  The condition that $A^T A$ has ones everywhere else is the same as requiring that any two different subsets intersect at a unique point.

A collection of $n$ $k$ element subsets of an $n$ element set with these properties defines a finite projective plane.  One fairly easy condition we get is that $n = k^2 -k +1$.  A much harder theorem is the Bruck-Ryser-Chowla theorem which restricts which possible values of $k$ we can have, based on its residue mod 4 and whether or not it is a sum of two squares. There is a construction for when $k-1$ is a prime power, and it is conjectured that these are the only values of $k$ that work.

Comment: This actually why and how I built that matrix : to get all those conditions of a generalised Dobble card game in one equation + one condition (only 0s and 1s) instead of writing each the n cards contains k pictures. There are n pictures in total. There is one and only one common picture for any pair of card. Finally I got to this k^2-k+1 by hand without using the equation, but I thought that would have been helpful. And now, even knowing n=k^2-k+1, I can't seem to find a way to build this A matrix.

Comment: thanks Nate, wow I am impressed. i stopped at the calculation of n. Then came back to my notes to try and solve the problem : and indeed I found a way using dots and lines in the $Z/(k-1)Z$ square. But then the parallel lines really don't cross and the others cross only one for (k-1) prime. And then I kind of gave up after spending my night on that and just before switcjing off looked back at your post and read "There is a construction for k-1 prime, and it is conjectured that these are the only values ...". I ll look into the mod 4 residues stuff later when I have more time for leisure maths

Answer (score 0):

Such a matrix does not exist. Suppose $A = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & \dots & v_n\end{bmatrix}$. Then the first entry of $A^T A$ will be $v_1^T v_1=k$ as each column sums to $k$ and the matrix only consists of ones and zeros. But you require it to be $k+1$.

Comment: Yes sorry, i meant all 1s and ks on the diagonal (so that would be (k-1).I instead of 1.